# How to add a folder in HMVC structure CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have file structure in CodeIgniter for HMVC everything is working fine

But I want file structure like

```
modules
    admin
        user
            controller
            view
            model
        profile
            controller
            view
            model
    frontend
        login
,           controller
            view
            model
```

Currently it's working fine with this file structure

```
modules
    user
        controller
        view
        model
    profile
        controller
        view
        model
```

So how can use as i mentioed above i just to add a folder before.

I want the URL like example.com/admin/user

Currently working example.com/user

Comment: I don't know but my mate made a bunch of codeigniter HMVC videos here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ&list=PLBEpR3pmwCawDZ6FgNYoyvicEz4HrJPec

Comment: Thanks, I'll check now. Maybe I'll get some idea.

Comment: You could make admin and frontend directories in the controller, model and view controller. That's how I usually do this. You can than just load like this $this->load->view('admin/viewname');

Comment: I know that but i am not looking for this. Thanks for your advice

Comment: I have been looking in the core, and what you want will require a lot of hacking into the core. I don't believe you can do this with routing only. I would not do this if I were you. You will have to hack /system/core/Loader.php if you still want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your route like this

```
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/(:any)/(:any)'] = '$1/$1_admin/$2/$3';
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/(:any)'] = '$1/$1_admin/$2';
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z_-]+)'] = '$1/$1_admin/index';
```

And change your class name controller
Like this

```
class User_admin extends CI_Controller
{
 ...
}
```

You can see my code on github
[github.com/caktopik/haci](https://github.com/caktopik/haci)

Or if you want to create admin panel please read this
https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/07/08/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter/